# Jekyll Posts Not Rendering Locally

Tags: jekyll

When I click on a post on my local instance of Jekyll, all I see is a directory with `index.html.textile`.

My GitHub.io page works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install textile plugin. [See documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-textile-converter).